# Delete multiple tables in a single query MySQL/Hibernate/jpa

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete data from multiple tables using inner join query but the data is not deleting and the executed message is showing "**0 rows affected**". I am using MySQL Workbench to execute the query.

```
delete r,ap,f,a from report r 
            inner join applied_positions ap on r.position_id=ap.position_id and r.user_id=ap.user_id
            inner join feedback f on r.position_id=f.position_id and r.user_id=f.user_id
            inner join answeer a on r.user_id=a.userID and r.position_id=a.position
            where r.user_id=? and r.position_id=?;
```

Comment: first run a select to see if any rows match your joined tables with the where clause. i am guessing not

Comment: @nbk I ran select query it was still showing "0 rows affected" message so I changed the inner join to left join now it is working. I found that feedback table was empty could it be the reason?

Comment: yes with an inner join  and no data the result set is empty, there you have it and a select with the criteria is always a swift way to check before hand

Comment: @nbk Thank you. I will keep it in mind.